# State of mixin not seen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a mixin with a method that checks if a user is logged in:

```
authenticated: function() {
    return this.state.currentUser !== null;
},
```

I am including this mixin in another component and I'm calling it like this:

```
mixins: [currentUserMixin],

checkUserAlreadyLoggedIn: function(nextState, replace) {
    if(this.authenticated()) {
      replace("/");
    }
},
```

However, in the chrome console I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentUser' of null
```

It looks like the state of the mixin is not imported in the state of the other component.
Why is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure your initial state object exists in either your mixin or your component.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    currentUser: null
  };
}
```

See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getinitialstate